# Bulbs: g.vertices.index.lookup(dpi=dpid_str) not working as expected

Tags: cassandra, titan, bulbs

I am using TitanGraphDB + Cassandra.I am starting Titan as follows

```
cd titan-cassandra-0.3.1
bin/titan.sh config/titan-server-rexster.xml config/titan-server-cassandra.properties
```

I have a Rexster shell that I can use to communicate to Titan+Cassandra above.

```
cd rexster-console-2.3.0
bin/rexster-console.sh
```

I want to program the Titan Graph DB from my python program.I am using bulbs package for that.

I create 3 types of vertices from python using bulbs as given below.
The 3 types of vertices are

```
- switch
- port
- device

from bulbs.titan import Graph
 vswitch = self.g.vertices.get_or_create('dpid',dpid_str,{'state':'active','dpid':dpid_str,'type':'switch'})
 vport   = self.g.vertices.get_or_create('port_id',port_id,{'desc':desc,'port_id':port_id,'state':state,'port_state':port_state,'number':number,'type':'port'})
```

If I try to print out the variables vswitch,vport and vdevice I get the following results.

```
vswitch     <Vertex: http://localhost:8182/graphs/graph/vertices/4>
vport       <Vertex: http://localhost:8182/graphs/graph/vertices/28>
```

However If I try to retrieve the above vertices using a key as follows.

```
vswitch = self.g.vertices.index.lookup(dpid=dpid_str)
vport   = self.g.vertices.index.lookup(port_id=port_id_str)
```

And try to print-out vswitch and vport variables I get the following values

```
<generator object <genexpr> at 0x26d6370>)
<generator object <genexpr> at 0x26d63c0>
```

Am I doing something WRONG in trying to retrieve vertices as above using g.vertices.index.lookup(dpid=dpid_str)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Bulbs `g.vertices.index.lookup()` method returns a [Python generator](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators) (which is a type of [iterator](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#iterator-types)).

Use `next()` to get the next value in the generator:

```
>>> # lookup() returns an generator (can return more than 1 value)

>>> switches = self.g.vertices.index.lookup(dpid=dpid_str)
>>> switch = switches.next()

>>> ports   = self.g.vertices.index.lookup(port_id=port_id_str)
>>> port = ports.next()
```

Or you can use `list()` to turn the `generator` into a Python `list`:

```
>>> switches = self.g.vertices.index.lookup(dpid=dpid_str)
>>> list(switches)

>>> ports   = self.g.vertices.index.lookup(port_id=port_id_str)
>>> list(ports)
```

However, if the indexed item is unique, you can use the `get_unique()` method to return one value or `None`:

```
# returns 1 vertex or None (errors if more than 1)
>>> vertex = g.vertices.index.get_unique( "dpid", dpid_str)
```

See...

Rexter index documentation:

- http://bulbflow.com/docs/api/bulbs/rexster/indices/

`index.lookup()`
https://github.com/espeed/bulbs/blob/afa28ccbacd2fb92e0039800090b8aa8bf2c6813/bulbs/titan/index.py#L251

`index.get_unique()`
https://github.com/espeed/bulbs/blob/afa28ccbacd2fb92e0039800090b8aa8bf2c6813/bulbs/titan/index.py#L274

> **NOTE**: Iterators and generators are Python programming basics -- they're used everywhere and are not specific to Bulbs -- if you're new
>   to Python programming, see my answer to [How Can I Learn to Program in
>   Python?](http://www.quora.com/Python-programming-language-1/How-can-I-learn-to-program-in-Python) for a list of good online resources for learning to program in Python.